# Timezone of ZonedDateTime changed to UTC during auto conversion of RequestBody with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller, zoneddatetime

I'm trying to keep ZoneId of ZonedDateTime which is set on front-end while performing POST/PUT to Spring Boot controller.

The value I want to transfer is:
`2019-05-01T00:00:00+01:00[Europe/Zagreb]`

After POST/PUT the ZoneId is converted to UTC and hours are adjusted. Technically this updated value represents the same point on time line, but the original ZoneId is lost and I would like to have it stored to be able to show it back later to end user.

```
// DTO
public class PriceInfoDTO {
    @JsonFormat( pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX['['VV']']", 
        with = JsonFormat.Feature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID )
    @DateTimeFormat( pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX['['VV']']", iso = ISO.DATE_TIME )
    private ZonedDateTime validFrom;
}


// Controller
@PutMapping(
    path = PATH + "/{id}",
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<PriceInfo> update(
    @PathVariable("id") final Integer id,
    @RequestBody final PriceInfoDTO dto
) {
    System.out.println(dto);
    ...
}
```

Looking at Network tab in my browser, the request from browser to Spring Controller has this value (payload):

```
2019-05-01T00:00:00+01:00[Europe/Zagreb]
```

which is the same as format pattern.

When I dump DTO to console, I get this result:

```
2019-04-30T22:00Z[UTC]
```

Is there any way to preserve ZoneId as it was received in a request? Should I write my own Serializer and Deserializer to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following line to the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE = false
```

---

References:

- Baeldung: *Jackson Date:* [Deserialize Joda ZonedDateTime with Time Zone Preserved](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates#12-deserialize-joda-zoneddatetime-with-time-zone-preserved)
- Javadoc: *jackson-databind 2.6.0 API:* [ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
- Spring Boot: *“How-to” Guides:* [Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

Comment: Can I disable this only for one field?

Answer (score 6):

Can also be set programmatically with `ObjectMapper` :

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID, true);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false);
```